# Magento 2 - Customize contact us page

Tags: magento2, contact-us

I want to add MAP in contact us page. To do this I want to override it's phtml.

How can I get it's phtml and how can I override it?

Thanks

Comment: You may not have to override the template , You can use update handle and add your block to existing template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy below file

> /vendor/magento/module-contact/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml

add this file below location

> app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[Your
>   Theme]/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml

after call static block

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()
          ->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
          ->setBlockId('your_block_identifier')
          ->toHtml();
```

here create static block in admin and block id is '`your_block_identifier`'  and add map

Comment: Sure, I was about to do it :)

Comment: I really appreciate you took time to answer my question :)

Comment: my  pleasure.... @MuhammadAnas